# Gradle failed to refresh Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Ive been installing and re-installing AndroidStudio since i keep getting the error

```
>  Gradle 'android' project refresh failed:
>                Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "language".
```

All of my group members can open up the project without receiving this error except me.I am in dire need of help,i just want to finish my group project for the semester.Thank you for your help.

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
```

build.gradle in the app folder

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar')
}
```

build.gradle in the gradle folder

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Update:did another re-intstall of Android Studio and now its giving me this error.

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'android'
           Out of memory: Java heap space. Configure Gradle memory settings using '-Xmx' JVM option (e.g. '-Xmx2048m'.)
           Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
           Gradle settings
```

Comment: any code around this error?

Comment: Can you post your "build.gradle" file.  Also, the "settings.gradle" file.  Is it possible that these files are different for you than for your team mates?  What version control system are you using?

Comment: sorry about not posting the gradle files,i completely forgot to.But we are using git for version control.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for posting.  Nothing is jumping out as wrong with the files.  Though you do have a fairly old version of the android gradle plugin (0.7.+).  The new version is 0.9.+.  Any reason you're not bumping the version?

Comment: Check the update AndroidGuy,and also i believe the rest of my team is using this version of the gradle,wasnt sure if changing it would do anything different.

Answer (score 0):

You might have typed closed quote (“) instead of open quote("). Change the quotes at start and end of attribute.

Comment: Assuming the OP is accurate, then how would the group members have this open with no issues then?